# JSON key exists but returns false

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

First of all, all my code is done in node.js but this can all be applied to javascript too.

This is my code I use to check if the keys exist, the problem is that it always returns false. So I added in the console.log to shows what the values are:

```
if(!choice.name || !choice.realm || !choice.region || !choice.roll){
    console.log(choice);
    console.log(choice.name);
    console.log(choice.realm);
    console.log(choice.region);
    console.log(choice.roll);
    return false;
}
```

This is the output of that:

```
{"name":"Imacactus","realm":"Velen","region":"US","roll":"DPS"}
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the quotes? but I've never heard of quotes messing it up. Is this a node.js problem? I've also tried .hasOwnProperty('realm') and it still failed.

This is most of the code with all the functions: http://pastebin.com/DUN9VdHr

Comment: I don't think you've posted quite enough code. Can you show how you get to that point, and specifically what you do that assigns that object to "choice"?

Comment: Alright, one sec I'll add most of it to a pastebin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse your json into a javascript object before you can reference its properties.

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var choiceobj = JSON.parse(choice);
if(!choiceobj.name || !choiceobj.realm || !choiceobj.region || !choiceobj.roll){

    console.log(choiceobj);
    console.log(choiceobj.name);
    console.log(choicepbj.realm);
    console.log(choiceobj.region);
    console.log(choiceobj.roll);
    return false;
```

}

Comment: That seems to be quite a plausible explanation. We can't see how `choice` is defined, but if it was a string of JSON instead of an object then this is the result I'd expect.

Comment: Thats what it looks like at least.

Comment: Sometimes the simple ones are the easiest to overlook and the hardest to debug.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the quotes is part of the key so to access it you have to do something like:
    `console.log(choice['"name"']);`